# Android PhoneStateListener onPhoneStateChanged method not invoked from service

Tags: android, android-service, phone-state-listener

I am working on a app that runs in the background and listens to incoming calls.

For this I have created a service which calls TelephonyManager.listen in the onHandleIntent method.

Unfortunately although the constructor of the phonestatelistener is invoked, its onPhoneStateChanged method is not getting invoked.

Making the same call from a activity works fine. I am confused what the issue might be. I have searched many similar posts but none of them have answered my question satisfactorily. Hence I am posting this question.

Following is my service and phonelistener implementation:

```
public class PhoneListenersService extends IntentService{

TelephonyManager tm;
CallStateListener callstatelistener;
public PhoneListenersService() {
    super("PhoneListenersService");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    int count=0;
    do
    {
        TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        TelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        Log.d("Count", ""+count++);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    while(count<100);
}

 class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {

     public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
           super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
           switch (state) {
           case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            // CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_IDLE",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
           case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            // CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
           case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            // CALL_STATE_RINGING
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), incomingNumber,
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_RINGING",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
           default:
            break;
           }
          }

         }
```

}

Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: How is the IntentService fired ? on which event ?

Comment: @MadhurAhuja you have invoke the IntentService using StartService method. The startService can be invoked at the click of a button or a similar form of trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Left with no option, I have changed my approach. I use Broadcast Receiver with Intent Service to listen for incoming calls. Following is the code if it helps someone:-

```
public class PhoneListenersService extends IntentService{

    TelephonyManager tm; 
    BroadcastReceiver receiver; 
    IntentFilter filter;

    public PhoneListenersService() { 
        super("PhoneListenersService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
    }

    @Override   
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            //Intent
 Filter         filter=new IntentFilter();  
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"); 
        //Create instance of BroadcastReceiver  
    receiver=new BroadcastReceiver()
{       
    @Override       
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                   if (bundle == null)
                      return;

                   // Incoming call
                   String state = 

bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

                   if ((state != null) &&  

(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))) 
{
                       phoneNumber = 

bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER); 

                       //if phoneNumber is not blank get location details

                       if(!phoneNumber.isEmpty())
                       {
                        //Do work here
                       }                       
                   }        
    }            
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);     
} }
```

Regards.